# vstest.console.exe generating empty .trx file even after executing the Test Cases from the team city build agent

Tags: teamcity, vstest

After executing the test cases successfully through the team city vstest.console.exe runner, the test result file that is being generated doesn't contain any test summary. The team city logs are as follows:-

1. Total tests: 69. Passed: 50. Failed: 19. Skipped: 0.
2. Importing data from 'TestResults\skolli_SRVBUILDW10-BNG 2016-03-14 3.
   16_19_19.trx' (1.17 KB) with 'vstest' processor
3. Test Run Failed.
4. VSTest report watcher
5. Test execution time: 1.8196 Minutes
6. VSTest
7. There were no test definitions found. Wrong or broken .trx file?
8. There were no tests reported. Wrong or broken .trx file?
9. Process exited with code 1

Can anyone tell me what is wrong?